# Select is not applying where clause insite a procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform this query inside a procedure

```
set mailSeq = (
select  MailSequence
from    MailIdentity
where   Customer = customer 
    and MailDate = mailDate
);
```

i have 4 records in this table

```
Id  Customer MailDate            MailSequence
1   1        2014-04-05 00:00:00 5
2   1        2014-04-06 00:00:00 2
3   2        2014-04-05 00:00:00 9
4   2        2014-04-06 00:00:00 5
```

i call the procedure as 
`call my_procedure(2, '2014-04-05')`

the parameters are customer and mail date

if I perform the query outside the procedure it returns a single record, the one i want, but when i call the procedure it returns the 4 records.

Can any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after reading this I realized what it was. Don't have you input parameter be the same name as the fieldname in your where clause.

Answer (score -1):

I also got this problem,and I found that the parameter after where:

```
like where Customer = customer 
    and MailDate = mailDate
```

the  left and right side is the same  ,so where is true forever